# Chart.js - is there a way to extend an existing scale?

Tags: chart.js

In Chart.js new axes can be made by extending `Scale` with

```
let MyScale = Chart.Scale.extend({
    /* extensions ... */
});
```

I'm trying to build a new axis which is pretty similar to `RadialLinearScale` and I just need to override a function or two.

Is there a way I can extend from `RadialLinearScale` to make a new scale or do I need to make a new one from ground up?

Answer (score 1):

I came across your post when I was looking for almost the same as you.
So far, what I saw that was possible was something like:

```js
var TimelineScale = Chart.scaleService.getScaleConstructor('time').extend({
    
  determineDataLimits: function() {
    var me = this;
    // ...
  }
    
});
```

You can see an example like this on the [chartjs-chart-timeline](https://github.com/fanthos/chartjs-chart-timeline) plugin.

Comment: This is perfect. The string passed to `getScaleConstructor` is the id of the scale type - so to answer the original question,  you would use `getScaleConstructor('radialLinear')`